# Trying to import a LibGDX program into NetBeans, but for some reason I can't

Tags: netbeans, libgdx

So, as stated, I'm trying to import a libGDX project into Netbeans but it keeps saying that it cannot load either the desktop and core parts of the project[As stated:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBwPX.png)

I have tried most things I knew how to do (Which weren't many), like deleting and generating new projects, also tried to look into the plugins, but nothing that solved the problem